# flex build error when using assets as RSL

Tags: apache-flex, build, flash-builder

Hi recently I converted all images inside the assets folder into separate swc. I now refer the swc as RSL in the build path. First time it worked. But now whenever I try to build the project the build fails showing the java heap error. When I referred the error logs. This was written in it.

```
!ENTRY com.adobe.flexbuilder.project 4 43 2012-11-22 15:12:15.797
!MESSAGE WARNING: setAssetClassAttribute - Unable to get definition for class GeneratedAsset11:null
!STACK 0
java.lang.Exception
at com.adobe.flexbuilder.project.internal.FlexProjectCore.createErrorStatus(FlexProjectCore.java:1019)
.....
.....
.....
.....
!ENTRY com.adobe.flexbuilder.project 4 43 2012-11-22 17:53:26.386
!MESSAGE Exception in design view callback:null
!STACK 0
java.lang.Exception
.......
.......
.......
!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.jobs 4 2 2012-11-22 18:07:48.821
!MESSAGE An internal error occurred during: "Build Project".
!STACK 0
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

Any pointer why this is happening??

Comment: How big are these assets? Could it be the compiler is having trouble loading it all into memory?

Comment: @RIAstar actually I did the separation of assets into separate swc to reduce the final swf size. Initially it had worked, the swc was converted into swf and placed inside the debug folder. But when I tried to clean the project this error started coming. To solve it I tried to restart the flashbuilder, changed the linkage of the swc from RSL to merge into code, rebuilt the swc but no success. The error log has 3 types of errors. They are

Comment: The errors are mentioned above in the question itself. (1)setAssetClassAttribute - Unable to get definition for class GeneratedAsset11  (2) MESSAGE Exception in design view callback:null !(3)An internal error occurred during: "Build Project". !STACK 0 java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Comment: I'm pretty sure all these different errors have only one root cause: lack of available memory. Have you given FlashBuilder more memory (through the .ini file)? Are you running an older version of FB (which might not manage memory as well as more recent releases)? Try removing a significant amount of assets from the lib and see what happens then.

Comment: yes I also thinking the same. I will try your suggestion. Thanks